# Generic Inquiry - Format result column with two decimal places as number

Tags: acumatica

In a generic inquiry, if I have a calculation field such as an aggregate SUM field is there a method to make the output column show as a number with 2 decimal places if no field in the GI schema matches that format?

For example, if I have a field SUM  {TABLE} [TABLE.FIELD]/60, the resulting field only shows an integer value of say 40 instead of 40.50.

Comment: Part of the problem appears to be the fact that some rows are null.   Using the following: =IsNull([EPTimeCardSummary.TimeSpent]/60.00,0.00) returns 40.500000.   Still need to get the right decimal places to show in the grid though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the formatting of the column by setting the "Schema Field" column of the generic inquiry "Results Grid" tab to any field in the table which matches the type and output format you're looking for.

In your case, you could use EPTimeCard.TimeSpentCalc, but this one assumes that you're passing a total of minutes, so division by 60 you're doing would need to be removed and system would format just like it does on screen in HH:MM format

Comment: So just to confirm..  If the GI does not contain the required format a DAC field has to be added as a customization to get the required format.       In this case the timespentcalc resulted in an empty display.  This might be a bug in 5.1 and I'll open a ticket accordingly

Comment: It's inly because you're doing a calculation and system can't infer the formatting from it. Typically you'd have another field in the DAC which will have the right format, but in you're case you'd have to do a custom, unbound field. You might as well but the calculation over there too through a PXFormula if possible....

Comment: Right.    I am going to open a ticket on the display as well.. removed the formula from the list so the line shows:   Caption: Total Time, Aggregate Function: SUM, Object: EPTimeCardSummary, Data Field: TimeSpent, Schema Field: EPTimeCard.TotalSpentCalc.     This results in a column with no values.   Going to accept this as the answer though as it does answer my question and confirms my thoughts.   Thank you as always

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
[TimeEntry.TimeSpent]/60.00

That produces 2.50 where as the following produces 2:
[TimeEntry.TimeSpent]/60